# Diffusion in a bounded domain

Tags: pr.probability

Let us consider an $\mathbb{R}^d$ diffusion

$$dX_t = dW_t +\mu(X_t)dt.$$

Let further $D\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded connected open domain. By $Y^D$ we denote the diffusion $X$ restricted to $D$ (reflected on the boundary or conditioned to stay inside). Then $Y^D$ converges exponentially fast to its stationary distribution, denote the ratio of the convergence by $r^{D,\mu}>0$.

**Question:** Is it true that there exists $r^{D}>0$ such that for any $\mu$ we have $r^{D,\mu}\geq r^D$.

My impression is that essentially the worse case is $\mu \equiv 0$ and any drift would only help. (I am not interested in pathologies e.g. I am happy to assume some smoothness if necessary.)

Comment: If $\mu$ is not bounded by an a-priori constant then certainly what you want fails. Think of $\mu$ creating two metastable equilibria in $D$ (that is, assume the ODE $dx/dt=\mu(x)$ has two stable points inside $D$), and that the situation is symmetric wrt these two points. Then convergence to equilibrium becomes slower and slower when $\mu$ increases.

Comment: You are right. I am happy to assume that $\mu$ is bounded. 

I guess my question above might be better stated vaguely as follows:
"Is there a simple lower-bound for the rate of convergence. By simple I understand something which involves as "little information" about the geometry of the $D$ and "little information" about $\mu$." 

Probably such an estimate cannot be very sharp but it is a price I am willing to pay :).

Answer (score 2):

To answer the rephrased question: is there a simple lower-bound for the rate of convergence?  Yes: assuming certain conditions hold, which I describe below.

For any $t \ge 0$, let $\Pi_t(x, \cdot)$ denote the transition probability of the process $X_t$ defined as: $$
\Pi_t(x,A) = \mathbb{P}(X_t \in A ~\mid~ X_0= x )
$$
for any measurable set $A \subset D$.  It is sufficient to establish a *Doeblin condition*, which is not impractical to obtain since the domain of the diffusion is bounded.  This condition requires that there exist $t \ge 0$, a constant $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and a probability measure $\nu$ on $D$ such that
$$
\inf_{x \in D} \Pi_t(x, A) \ge \alpha \nu(A) \;.
$$
for all measurable sets $A \subset D$.  If this Doeblin condition holds, then one can apply a coupling inequality to show that the rate of convergence of $\Pi_t(x,\cdot)$ to equilibrium is determined by the parameter $\alpha$ appearing in this bound.

The usual way to guarantee that this condition holds is to show that $X_t$ is irreducible and its associated semigroup is strongly Feller, see e.g. Section 4 of [Hairer 2001](http://www.hairer.org/papers/exp.pdf).  To prove that a diffusion on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is irreducible and its associated semigroup is strongly Feller, it is sufficient to assume that the drift field $\mu$ of the diffusion is locally Lipschitz continuous with at most polynomial growth at infinity, see Chapter 2 of *Second Order PDE's in Finite and Infinite Dimension. S. Cerrai. Springer, 2001.*

On a bounded domain, and depending on the assumed boundary conditions, other assumptions may be needed to prove irreducibility and the strong Feller property, including a regularity assumption on the boundary, e.g., that the boundary is twice differentiable; for precise conditions see Chapter 4 of *Linear and Quasilinear Equations of Parabolic Type. Ladyzensakaja et al.  American Mathematical Society, 1967* or other textbooks that discuss existence and properties of classical solutions to linear PDEs of parabolic type on bounded domains.

Note that, in contrast to diffusions on $\mathbb{R}^d$, for bounded diffusions one does not need to assume that the drift is dissipative.  In fact, it suffices to assume enough regularity on $\mu$ and $\partial D$ such that the above Doeblin condition holds.